# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes 2034 and 2034,2

Tags: javascript, object-detection, tensorflow.js, object-detection-api, mobilenet

I trained a mobilenet_v3_small model using Tensorflow version 1.15.2 (object detection API), then converted it to tfjs.
I was able to make predictions in python but when I try to run the model using tfjs, I get the above error.
I am not sure that it's related directly but in the .json file the number 2034 appears in: ...{"name": "Postprocessor/ExpandDims", "shape": [1, 2034, 3], "dtype": "float32"}.

Comment: The problem is an tensor dimensions issue. I would request you share some minimal reproducible code.

Comment: shape [2034] and [2034,2] have different number of elements, by 2x to be specific. need reproduction with actual model used as i'm assuming this is not due to simple input shape mismatch.

Comment: I am not sure that I can share the model, but I have found something that may help. While exporting the model (using export_inference_graph.py) I got these two summaries: 1. End of Report: 206 ops no flops stats due to incomplete shapes.
Parsing Inputs...
Incomplete shape. 2. Model Analysis Report: Incomplete shape. I am not sure what they are referring to, but it feels related. Another thought - does it matter which tfjs version and/or tfjs converter I am using to convert a Tensorflow 1.15.2 version model? Thank you very much for trying to help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.